# My Flutter app blocks all requests on some Android models

Tags: android, flutter, dart, huawei-mobile-services

I've been having some problems with my app in production, some Huawei users have complained that the app doesn't leave the home page. When I go to see the log requests, I see that no requests are made. Any other users do not have this problem.

I don't know if it's a problem with the type of processor the phone uses, or if there's some sort of firewall blocking.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked usecleartext attribute in AndroidManifest.xml? Maybe you are trying to communicate a non-https service.

[See more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)